# Keep WTelegram.Client persistent between user requests?

Tags: asp.net, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I have two handler methods in razor pages for:

1. request telegram code.
2. send verification code.

How can I keep an instance of Wtelegram Client between requests?
I tried JsonSerializer but got below error!

> Serialization and deserialization of 'WTelegram.Client+TcpFactory'
> instances are not supported. Path: $.TcpHandler

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCodeAsync()
{
  var wClient = new Client(Config, store);

  HttpContext.Session.SetString(telSession, JsonSerializer.Serialize(wClient));

  Msg = await _wClient.Login(PhoneNumber);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostVerifyAsync()
{
  var value = HttpContext.Session.GetString(telSession);

  var wClient = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Client>(value);

  Msg = await wClient.Login(VerificationCode);
}
```

Or how can I tell WTelegram to continue another sign in process using simple string and int properties?

Comment: create a single background task which handles communication between your api and telegram, or you could connect/disconnect the client for each request, it will work since the steps and session is stored on the hdd!

Comment: @AliSalehi A session would be created when login finished successfully.

Answer (score 2):

See the [official ASP.NET example](https://wiz0u.github.io/WTelegramClient/Examples/ASPnet_webapp.zip) showing how to keep a singleton of the client/service while performing the login and further API calls.